# .htaccess redirect to HTTPS doesn't work correctly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Redirect works only on the first page,  `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`.
 
But it doesn't work on subfolders: `http://example.com/news` or `/news/category` etc. redirects me to the `https://example.com/index.php` (My website is on Laravel 5.5).
Any suggestions pls?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# ensure !www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://glyphicons.com/"  

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Remember to replace  example.com and www.example.com with your actual domain name

Comment: Removed www. from your example, cause I don't need it and it works perfectly to me. Thanks.